# Sort data by date, time, and name from Mysql database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been really struggling to sort this data by date and time. As you can see, I have got this data. In addition, the data table is not taking the same space as the dataGridView space. How do I resolve that problem?

[image]

I am trying to sort out this data in c#. I have generated the above table by writing the below code:

```
private void ViewAppointment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=****;username=root;password=****;database=appointment; pooling = false; convert zero datetime = True");
                string Query = "SELECT * FROM `appointmentdetails`";
                MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);

                MySqlDataAdapter myAdapater = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                myAdapater.SelectCommand = myCommand;
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                myAdapater.Fill(dTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: add the sorting in the SQL query using the Order By clause

Comment: @PaulKaram I tried that one like:                                                                            
                                                                                                                               SELECT `Name`, `Email`, date(`Date`) as dateOne, `Time`, `Preferred GP/Nurse Name` FROM appointmentdetails
ORDER BY (Date)DESC;                                                                                                                      But it didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either sort directly on the `DataGrid`:

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Date"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Or get the data sorted from `sql`:

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM `appointmentdetails` order by Date";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your sorting to the Query

```
private void ViewAppointment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=****;username=root;password=****;database=appointment; pooling = false; convert zero datetime = True");
                string Query = "SELECT * FROM `appointmentdetails ORDER BY date DESC`";
                MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);

                MySqlDataAdapter myAdapater = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                myAdapater.SelectCommand = myCommand;
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                myAdapater.Fill(dTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```